# How to tackle this RuntimeException?

Tags: android, android-activity, runtimeexception

I'm not getting this issue but a friend is so he sent me the stack trace as he lives too far away for me to check his device. This issue seems ambiguous to me so I'm not sure where to check first. What should I do?

note: I've attached my `MainActivity.onCreate` below this trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxxx.android.phone.xxxx/xxxx.android.phone.xxxx.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class shared.ui.actionscontentview.ActionsContentView
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class shared.ui.actionscontentview.ActionsContentView
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
       at xxxx.android.phone.xxxx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:145)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
       at xxxx.android.phone.xxxx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:145)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START }
       at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1674)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1773)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1751)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:538)
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.e()
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a()
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity$a.a()
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.initialize()
       at xxxx.android.phone.xxxx.MainActivity.initYouTubePlayer(MainActivity.java:509)
       at xxxx.android.phone.xxxx.layout.MainContainer.onFinishInflate(MainContainer.java:73)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:814)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at shared.ui.actionscontentview.ActionsContentView.<init>(ActionsContentView.java:217)
       at shared.ui.actionscontentview.ActionsContentView.<init>(ActionsContentView.java:136)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
       at xxxx.android.phone.xxxx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:145)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

## MainActivity.onCreate

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
          MainActivity.instance = this;
          this.className = this.getClass().getSimpleName();                     

    // get login credentials
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(xxxx.PREFS, 0);
    xxxx.instance.currentUserEmail = settings.getString(xxxx.PREFS_KEY_SAVED_EMAIL, "");
    xxxx.instance.currentUserPassword = settings.getString(xxxx.PREFS_KEY_SAVED_PASSWORD, "");

    if(MainActivity.CACHING_ENABLED) {              
          // set up image cache
           ImageCache.ImageCacheParams imageCacheParams = new ImageCache.ImageCacheParams(getApplicationContext(), IMAGE_CACHE_DIR);
           // Set image memory cache to 1/10th of mem class
           imageCacheParams.setMemCacheSizePercent(this, 0.1f);
           MainActivity._imageCache = new ImageCache(imageCacheParams);

          // set up xml cache
           XMLCache.XMLCacheParams xmlCacheParams = new XMLCache.XMLCacheParams(this, XML_CACHE_DIR);
           // Set xml memory cache to 1/10th of mem class
           xmlCacheParams.setMemCacheSizePercent(this, 0.1f);
           MainActivity._xmlCache = new XMLCache(xmlCacheParams);

           this.checkCacheFreshness();
    }

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
          //session = new Session.Builder(this).setApplicationId(getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_app_id)).build();
            session = new Session(this);
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        }
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.app_container);
    navSlider = (ActionsContentView) findViewById(R.id.actionsContentView);

    // use a tree observer and a global layout listener to get the available screen size and height -DJL
       final RelativeLayout fullScreenLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.fullScreenLayout);
       ViewTreeObserver vto = fullScreenLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
       vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                 public void onGlobalLayout() {                
                        //remove listener to ensure only one call is made.
                        fullScreenLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                        xxxx.instance.height = fullScreenLayout.getHeight();
                        xxxx.instance.width = fullScreenLayout.getWidth();
                        Log.v(xxxx.TAG, "Height: " + xxxx.instance.height);
                        Log.v(xxxx.TAG, "Width: " + xxxx.instance.width);

                        // Once we have the dimensions we load the featured page
                        Navigation.instance.featuredBtn.performClick();
                 };
          });

    // Load the quick tutorial activity if it has never been loaded
       SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(xxxx.PREFS, 0);

 // If the app has been updated, show the tutorial again
          if (xxxx.wasUpdated(getBaseContext())) {
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
          editor.putString(xxxx.PREFS_KEY_TUTORIAL_SHOWN, "false");
          editor.commit();
          }

          boolean tutShown = Boolean.parseBoolean(prefs.getString(xxxx.PREFS_KEY_TUTORIAL_SHOWN, null));
          //tutShown = false; // uncomment to display the tutorial every launch for testing

    if(!tutShown) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, TutorialActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
        // update the tutorial show preference
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
          editor.putString(xxxx.PREFS_KEY_TUTORIAL_SHOWN, "true");
          editor.commit();
    }

      boolean shouldPromptCheck = true;
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle != null) {
          shouldPromptCheck = bundle.getBoolean(xxxx.KEY_SHOULD_PROMPT_CHECK, true);
    }
    if(shouldPromptCheck) {
              xxxx.instance.performVersionCheck(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is [he running Android 5.0, perhaps](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1247)?

Comment: *Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START }*

Comment: The error is not coming from you onCreate method. In the last block of the stack trace it says it's in the 'initYouTubePlayer' Method. Your Intent to start youtube is invalid.

Comment: @Tanis.7x we are both on Android 5.0 but the app runs fine on my device, which is odd..

Comment: @MatF Looking at blackbelt's comment I think the intent mismatch is likely part of the YouTube api but I already have the latest version of the YouTube API which means I'm stuck if it's a problem inside the there.

Comment: Check out the link in my comment. It appears to be a known issue.

Comment: Have a look at line 6 of the ActionsContentView xml file.

Comment: ActionsContentView is not a part of my jurisdiction as it's part of an Android shared library. I suspect the issue will be resolved by @MatF's solution so I'm waiting to hear back about the testing on the latest APK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my versions of the Youtube SDK & Google Analytics SDKs and viola.